# Can i use signalr 2.x with .net 4.0 if I am using Microsoft.Bcl? (Upgrading from 1.x on .NET 4.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr

I know that Signalr 2.x was design for .NET 4.5.
Unfortunately, we cannot update our production server to .NET 4.5.
If I include the [Microsoft BCL libraries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/04/17/microsoft-bcl-async-is-now-stable.aspx), is it possible to use Signalr 2.x and target .NET framework 4.0.

**Note:**We are already using Signalr 1.x with .NET 4.0. I didn't state the specifically when submitting the question.

Comment: I understand what it says in the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms#updates)as given by @Jalpesh-Vadgama, but I was under the impression that this was because of async/await.If this is provided by the BCL, then does this satisfy the needed pieces form .NET 4.5

Comment: If .NET 4.0 is a requirement I would go for xsockets.net instead of signalr

Comment: the system already uses signalr and rewriting is not an option at this point. I will evaluate xsockets.net if we do have the option later, though by that time we may be able to upgrade production to .net 4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use Signal R 2.0 with 4.0. See the below link in that it is clearly mentioned that it will only supported in .NET 4.5 and higher framework.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms#updates

Answer (score 0):

You can use SignalR 1.x it supports .Net 4 ,

see here http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-1x/getting-started-with-aspnet-signalr/supported-platforms